# Calling SELECT * on a primary key versus an attribute in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, primary-key

I am currently studying for a final and have a question about one of the practice problems.

The problem states:

Consider the following two SQL queries over the relation `R(A,B)` where attribute `A` is the primary key.

Query 1: `SELECT * FROM R WHERE B > 50 OR B <= 50`

Query 2: `SELECT * FROM R WHERE A > 50 OR A <= 50`

Which is correct?

a. Queries 1 and 2 return all the records in `R`

b. Query 2 returns all the records in `R`, but Query 1 may not

The official answer says that b is correct, but I wanted to know why. I understand that a primary key must be unique, meaning Query 2 should return every record. But wouldn't query 1 also return every record even if there were duplicate `B` values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is the second, because A is a primary key and a primary key cannot be null, so

```
A > 50 OR A <= 50
```

will always be true, while the following:

```
B > 50 OR B <= 50
```

might be NULL if B is NULL

```
NULL > 50 OR NULL <= 50 ---> NULL
```

and rows whenever B is null won't be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can see why query 1 would not return some of the records is if column (or attribute as you call it) B is nullable.
When comparing null to any value in any rdbms I know you will never get correct results, since `null` is *by definition* an unknown value.
for example, if you add to your where clause `and null = null` you will get no results at all.

So any record where B is null would not be returned from the first query.

This cannot be the case for column A since it's the primary key, and a primary key can not be nullable *by definition*.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. What if there's a row with B null? It's not said that attribute B has to be not null, so query 1 will not return all rows with an empty (null) B value.

Instead, A is not nullable because it's the primary key.